# How to turn off exceptions in Microsoft compiler(cl)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cl

What compiler flags do I use to completely get rid of the exception handling?
I don't use them at all but the compiler still generates .pdata and .xdata sections which there for exception handling only.

Comment: IIRC They are disabled by default.

Comment: @RSahu i did. There is no such a flag.

Comment: I don't use at all the NumLock key, but the PC makers still put it on my keyboard.  How can I get rid of it ?

Comment: @Christophe i'm 12 so i would say make your uwn standart. May be people should not use this key, really and you are the one who can explain it well enough so that the standart change. I don't use exceptions because they shoulnot even exist, just like multiple inheritance, rtti and so on. I have a plan to change the industy in the near future.

Comment: @123qwe joke aside, unless you should think of potential consequences of mixing different exception handling code generation (e.g. your code and the code of your libraries), as explained here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524259/what-are-the-consequences-of-mixing-exception-handling-models-in-visual-studio-2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your project properties set the **Enable C++ Exceptions** to **No**:
[image: Disable C++ Exceptions]

and enable the unwind semantics by specifying the `/EHsc` flag:
[image: Unwind semantics]

To set this option on command line you would leave out the `/EHa`, `/EHsc` and `/EHs` flags from the `[option]` section as described in the [Compiler Command-Line Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610ecb4h.aspx) manual.
Further relevant MSDN reading:

- [/EH (Exception Handling
  Model)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model)
- [Compiler Options Listed by
  Category](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19z1t1wy.aspx)
- [Setting Compiler
  Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3600tzxa.aspx)

Comment: @ what is the option to turn off exceptions in the command line and not in the VS?

Comment: @123qwe I have updated the answer with the relevant info.

Comment: I downvoted because I think by now we have a more solid procedure and Knowledge Base, to do this. As I described in my answer below. In 2017 Ron could not predict the future, mu downvote is not a personal attack. I think anonymous downvoting should be stopped.

Comment: Setting No will remove /EHsc, which stands for Yes in "Enable C++ Exceptions" automatically, and readding same thing manually does not seem to have any observable effect

Answer (score 6):

This is my experience. And practice.

To disable C++ exceptions using cl.exe, one should do all of the following:

- /EHsc or any other [/EH combination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/eh-exception-handling-model?view=msvc-160), should not exist as a switch,
- /D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 must be used
- [/GR-](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gr-enable-run-time-type-information?view=msvc-160) disables the RTTI

That combination makes `try/throw/catch` into non-existent keywords. That is: you are in the non-standard C++ territory.

The `cl.exe` compiler **always** generates code that supports asynchronous structured exception handling ([SEH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp?view=msvc-160))

That means C or C++, SEH is "always there". I personally do use it. MS STL compiles and it is quite fast with the above switches combination. In (almost all of my) `main()` I catch the potential SE raised and then I [create a minidump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxtecharts/crash-dump-analysis) which Visual Studio can open and lead you to the exact position in code where the exception was raised.

We need to talk about the [`/kernel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/kernel-create-kernel-mode-binary?view=msvc-160) switch. It switches C++ exceptions off, in one go, and instructs the linker to produce "kernel mode" win executables, drivers, and such. `/GR-` still has to be used manually. I used it for standard desktop/console apps with no problems. Always using SEH of course.

NOTE: `_CPPUNWIND` you can not set. But you do use it in your code to check if C++ exceptions are on or off.

HTH

PS: I always use static runtime lib's: switches  `/MT` and `/MTd`. I think these days one does not need to do anything else in case dll runtimes are used, switches: `/MD` and `/MDd`. I am not 100% sure, please check e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870281/10870835).

Comment: Thanks for this answer! /EHs-c- /D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 works for me.

Comment: Thanks, @strager :)  perhaps `/EHs-c-` is not necessary. But as long as `_CPPUNWIND` behaves as expected it does not matter :)